HTML Javascript donut chart doesnt appear using Chart.js
I have this HTML code to show a donut chart with the database records retrieved from the database via a PHP script. The data is being retrieved successfully and can be seen on the browser console.
But the chart is not displayed. How do I fix this?


console.log('Script loaded'); // Check if script is loaded

// Fetch total number of students from PHP file using fetch API
fetch('/javatopia/api/lvTotalStudents.php')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    console.log('Total Students Data:', data); // Log total students data
    document.getElementById('totalStudents').innerHTML = 'There are currently <strong>' + data.totalStudents + '</strong> students enrolled.';
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('Error fetching total number of students:', error);
  });

// Fetch module names and IDs from PHP file using fetch API and populate dropdown menu
fetch('/javatopia/api/lvParticipationPerModule.php')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    console.log('Fetched Modules:', data); // Log fetched module data
    const moduleSelect = document.getElementById('moduleSelect');
    data.forEach(module => {
      const option = document.createElement('option');
      option.value = module.moduleId;
      option.text = module.moduleName;
      moduleSelect.appendChild(option);
    });
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('Error fetching module data:', error);
  });

// Fetch data for line chart and initialize the chart
fetch('/javatopia/api/lvPerformance.php')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    console.log('Line Chart Data:', data); // Log line chart data
    // Prepare data for Chart.js line chart
    const topics = Object.keys(data);
    const averageMarks = Object.values(data);
    const ctxLine = document.getElementById('averageMarks').getContext('2d');

    new Chart(ctxLine, {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
        labels: topics,
        datasets: [{
          label: 'Average Marks per Topic',
          data: averageMarks,
          fill: false,
          borderColor: 'rgb(75, 192, 192)',
          tension: 0.1
        }]
      },
      options: {
        scales: {
          y: {
            beginAtZero: true,
            max: 5, // Set the maximum value for the y-axis
          }
        }
      }
    });
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('Error fetching line chart data:', error);
  });

// Set default module ID and event listener for "Go" button click
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  console.log('DOM Loaded'); // Check if DOM is loaded
  const defaultModuleId = 3; // Set your default module ID here
  document.getElementById('moduleSelect').value = defaultModuleId;
  fetchModuleCompletionData(defaultModuleId);
});

document.getElementById('goButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log('Go Button Clicked'); // Check if Go button is clicked
  const selectedModuleId = document.getElementById('moduleSelect').value;
  fetchModuleCompletionData(selectedModuleId);
});

// Function to fetch and update module completion data for the donut chart
function fetchModuleCompletionData(moduleId) {
  moduleId = parseInt(moduleId); // Convert moduleId to a number
  console.log('Fetching Module Completion Data for Module ID:', moduleId);

  fetch(`/javatopia/api/lvParticipationPerModule.php?moduleId=${moduleId}`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      console.log('Module Completion Data:', data); // Log module completion data
      const ctxDonut = document.getElementById('moduleCompletionChart').getContext('2d');
      let moduleCompletionChart = window.moduleCompletionChart;
      if (moduleCompletionChart && moduleCompletionChart.data) {
        moduleCompletionChart.data.labels = ['Completed', 'Not Completed'];
        moduleCompletionChart.data.datasets[0].data = [data.completed, data.not_completed];
        moduleCompletionChart.update();
      } else {
        window.moduleCompletionChart = new Chart(ctxDonut, {
          type: 'doughnut',
          data: {
            labels: ['Completed', 'Not Completed'],
            datasets: [{
              label: 'Module Completion',
              data: [data.completed, data.not_completed],
              backgroundColor: ['#36A2EB', '#FF6384'],
              borderWidth: 1
            }]
          },
          options: {
            responsive: true,
            maintainAspectRatio: false
          }
        });
      }

      // Ensure the canvas is visible and not hidden
      const canvas = document.getElementById('moduleCompletionChart');
      if (canvas) {
        canvas.style.display = 'block';
      }
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error fetching module completion data:', error);
    });
}
<link href="/javatopia/lib/bootstrap/assets/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.7.0/chart.min.js"></script>

<div id="totalStudents" align="center" style="position: relative; margin-top: 3vw; margin-bottom: 0.5vw;"></div>
<div id="averagePointsPerTopic" class="chart-container" align="center" style="position: relative; height:20vh; width:40vw; margin-top: 2.5vw; margin-bottom: 15vw; margin-left: 30vw;">
  <h2>Average performance per topic</h2>
  <canvas id="averageMarks"></canvas>
</div>
<div id="donutChartContainer" align="center" style="position: relative; margin-left: 35vw; height: 20vw; width: 30vw; margin-top: 2.5vw; margin-bottom: 15vw;">
  <h2>Module Completion</h2>
  <select id="moduleSelect">
    <!-- Options will be populated dynamically -->
  </select>
  <button id="goButton">Go</button>
  <canvas id="moduleCompletionChart" style="display: block;"></canvas>
</div>



Below is the console log
lvDashboard3.2.html:24 Script loaded
lvDashboard3.2.html:92 DOM Loaded
lvDashboard3.2.html:107 Fetching Module Completion Data for Module ID: 3
lvDashboard3.2.html:30 Total Students Data: {totalStudents: 4}
lvDashboard3.2.html:58 Line Chart Data: {Intro: '2.50', Syntax: '3.75', Output: '2.50', Comments: '2.50'}
lvDashboard3.2.html:41 Fetched Modules: (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
lvDashboard3.2.html:112 Module Completion Data: (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]

Below is the response data from postman.
[
    {
        "moduleId": "3",
        "moduleName": "Intro",
        "completed": 4,
        "not_completed": 0
    },
    {
        "moduleId": "4",
        "moduleName": "Syntax",
        "completed": 4,
        "not_completed": 0
    },
    {
        "moduleId": "5",
        "moduleName": "Output",
        "completed": 4,
        "not_completed": 0
    },
    {
        "moduleId": "6",
        "moduleName": "Comments",
        "completed": 2,
        "not_completed": 2
    }
]


Look in the console for errors and then in the network tab and console.log the data. If the ajaxing works, then please [edit] and then click [<>]  and create a [mcve] with MOCK data instead of the ajax.

Please attach the response data in the question. Thanks.

console.log('Module Completion Data:', data); ==> Module Completion Data: (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}] then same data variable is used in [data.completed, data.not_completed], but the value of data is an array, not an object; so probably you forgot a step where you process the fetched data to get an object with completed and not_completed keys.

Yes, as @kikon mentioned, the response data returned for the doughnut chart is an array but you are processing it as an object.
Either you need to make the change in the back-end to return the response as an object as:
{
  "completed": 14,
  "not_completed": 2
}

Or you need to transform the data in JavaScript function, summing each completed and not_completed values in the array respectively
console.log('Module Completion Data:', data); // Log module completion data

let completed = data.map((x) => x.completed).reduce((acc, cur) => acc + cur, 0);
let not_completed = data
  .map((x) => x.not_completed)
  .reduce((acc, cur) => acc + cur, 0);

const ctxDonut = document
  .getElementById('moduleCompletionChart')
  .getContext('2d');
let moduleCompletionChart = window.moduleCompletionChart;
if (moduleCompletionChart && moduleCompletionChart.data) {
  moduleCompletionChart.data.labels = ['Completed', 'Not Completed'];
  moduleCompletionChart.data.datasets[0].data = [completed, not_completed];
  moduleCompletionChart.update();
} else {
  window.moduleCompletionChart = new Chart(ctxDonut, {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: {
      labels: ['Completed', 'Not Completed'],
      datasets: [
        {
          label: 'Module Completion',
          data: [completed, not_completed],
          backgroundColor: ['#36A2EB', '#FF6384'],
          borderWidth: 1,
        },
      ],
    },
    options: {
      responsive: true,
      maintainAspectRatio: false,
    },
  });
}

Demo @ StackBlitz
